# How can I save MonjaDB credentials to access MongoDB database?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying out MonjaDB (eclipse plugin) to access a remote sharded MongoDB database, but for every command I try to execute it keep asking the username and password, which makes the plugin baregly useful in this scenario.

The MonjaDB preferences page and connection wizard does not contain any information about how to persist credentials.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/Kanatoko/MonjaDB/issues/21.  Also suggests no good solution is forthcoming from the author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a connectivity issue where you lose the connection very so often that you need to input your credentials every time you try to run a command. I've never had this issue and have been using MonjaDB for quite some time.

You may try connecting to a database on a different host, or from a different machine to see if you can reproduce this issue.

Alternatively, there are many non-eclipse GUI MongoDB clients for various platforms that you may have to resort to.